# Find the rank of $A_n$ in terms of $n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

> Let $A_n$ be the real $n × n$ matrix $(n ≥ 2)$ whose $(i, j)$ entry is $i − j$. What is the rank of $A_n$ as a function of $n$?

My attempt:-
$A_2$ has rank $2$. It is obvious. $A_3$ has also rank $2$. Since, $A_3$ has determinant $0$ and has a submatrix of order $2$ with determinant non-zero. Similarly, I could conclude that $A_4$ has rank $2$. Using this method I can't go beyond. I also know that $A_n$ is a skew-symmetric matrix. $\det A_n=0,\forall n.$ I am not able to draw conclusion beyond this. Please help me.

Comment: Unless I'm misreading something, if $\det(A_3)=2$, then $A_3$ is invertible and so has full rank, i.e. 3.

Comment: OP has a typo (actually multiple). He said at the end that $det(A_n) = 0$, which is true for $n$ odd due to skew symmetrty. (actually, holds for all $n\neq 2$ of this form).

Comment: @CalvinLin: Please don't assume that a user must be male. There is a lot of discrimination against women in mathematics; defaulting to male pronouns perpetuates that bias.

Comment: @Reveillark Thank you for pointed out my mistake.

Comment: @GregMarting You are probably refering to the previous century, or in any case many, many years ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: Can you show that the matrix $B = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\ 2 & 2 & \cdots & 2  \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ n & n & \cdots & n\end{bmatrix}$ (i.e. $B_{i,j} = i$) has rank $1$?

Similarly, can you show that the matrix $C = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & \cdots & n \\ 1 & 2 & \cdots & n \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 1 & 2 & \cdots & n\end{bmatrix}$ (i.e. $C_{i,j} = j$) has rank $1$?

Once you do that, what can you say about the rank of $A = B-C$?

Comment: This is good. In different words, the OP should prove that the row space of $A_n$ is spanned by $(1,1,1,\ldots,1)$ and $(1,2,3,\ldots,n)$.

Comment: I could prove $B,C$ has rank $1$.

Comment: rank($A$) $\leq $ rank($B$)+rank($-C$)=$2$

Comment: Also, It has a submatrix of order 2 with non zero determinants. Hence Rank(A)$\ge 2$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That's the gist of my solution.

Comment: So it seems, @CalvinLin. It is always difficult to judge, how opaque you want to make your hints.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**   Show that column $k$ of the matrix is given by $A + k B$. (Find these column vectors)

Hence, the matrices have rank 2.

Comment: I don't understand your hint. Can you please expand it bit.

Comment: @Truth_searcher Assuming the hint, do you see why this tells us that the matrix has rank 2 if $B$ is not a multiple of $A$, rank 1 if $B$ is a multiple of $A$ and neither are 0, and rank 0 if $A = B = 0$?

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The upper left $2\times 2$ matrix is always the same and has rank $2$, so $\operatorname{rank}A_n\ge 2$ for all $n\ge 2$. Moreover,
$$
a_{1j}-a_{ij} = 1-j-(i-j) = 1-i
$$
means that subtracting row $i$ from row $1$ is always a multiple of the vector $(1,1,\ldots,1)$ and thus shows that $\operatorname{rank}A_n = 2$ for all $n$.

Comment: I understood your argument for $A_n\ge 2$. I don't understand the other way argument.

Comment: @Truth_searcher It means subtracting row $i$ from row $1$ is always a multiple of the vector $(1,1,\ldots,1)$. I edited.